# Fetch Data Row wise From StackMob and show in Android Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, fetch, stackmob

I am developing an app in android which has connectivity with stackmob. I want to fetch data from stackmob ,my fetch() method is working but it is not show any data in emulator.
Please someone tell me this.
Thanks!

Comment: Can anybody tell me it's answer............

Answer (score 0):

The UI has to be updated in a separate thread. Try something like this:

http://crodrigues.com/updating-the-ui-from-a-background-thread-on-android/